# I want to embed unity library in android studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Problem is that when I embed unityLibrary according to this url(https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/android.md), empty unityLibrary is embedded like image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIP4R.png)

UnityLibrary is supposed to look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CAK4.png)

Why empty unitylibrary keeps appearing???

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I set wrong path in settings.gradle. I needed to set Right path in this code(project(':unityLibrary').projectDir=new File('..\CheckYourPath')
)